# Setting SSL for JAX-WS Client

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere, jax-ws

I need to implement some JAX-WS client (for Websphere Application Server 7), that will request server using SSL. The question is, how to set SSL certificate into WS request dynamically? I want to use the way, which is presented here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjw_security_https.html
That means to use the setting SSL configuration alias for referencing to configuration. This looks easily, but this example is for JAX-RPC and I would like to know, if is possible this kind of configuration if I use JAX-WS. Is something like this possible with JAX-WS? Thanks

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) importIsdn;
        bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain().add(new Handler() {
            public boolean handleMessage(MessageContext context) {
                context.put("ssl.configName", wsClient.getSslConfigName());
                return true;
            }

            public boolean handleFault(MessageContext context) {
                return false;
            }

            public void close(MessageContext context) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JAX-WS, check if you can use [policy sets](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cwbs_wsspsps.html?lang=en) instead of doing it in the code.

Create policy based on `WSHTTPS default`, then in create binding and specify SSL configs to be used (you can select SSL configuration alias there). Attach policy to the JAX-WS client via admin console.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can reference this link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_configclienttransportsecprog.html